# Can we add a SVG object to a canvas in fabricjs as vector image - not pixel

Tags: svg, canvas, fabricjs

Of course I have read similar questions before asking. The most answers are about how to read SVG, turn it into pixel image and then add it to canvas.

My question is:
how can we create an object and put it into a canvas so it stays a vector object, not turning into pixels?

For example we can easily create a line using fabricjs and add it to canvas:

```
var blackLine = new fabric.Line([10, 10, 100, 100], {
    stroke: 'black'
});

function createCanvas(id){
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas(id);
    canvas.add(blackLine);

    return canvas;
}
```

It there a way to do something like (let's imagine):

```
var line = newSVG.Line([x1, y1, x2, y2])
canvas.add(line);
```

Comment: Canvas is a pixel-based graphic environment by definition. You can import SVG to canvas, but it will be converted. If you really want to have both at the same time, you might use element positioning and place an SVG element right above a canvas element (or the other way around).

Comment: Please read about [Path2D()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D)

Comment: @enxaneta I'm, afraid, Path2D() is making the same thing - the object on canvas is pixel, not vector